# Do while se repite cuando no deberia

Tags: java

El do while con la condición: while (completado == false || (opc != 5)); se repite cuando no debería. Y no se como solucionarlo llevo horas probando de todo pero nada.

Se supone que el do while debería de funcionar mientras completado == false o opc sea diferente de 5.

[image: Ejemplo del error]

y el código seria:

```
    do {
        if (i == 0) {
            tab_bckup = uno.getTablero();
            uno.ImprimirPartida();
            i++;
            completado = false;
        }
        System.out.print("Introduce una coordenada: ");
        uno.Datos(0);
        System.out.println("\n");
        opc = uno.Validar();
        switch (opc) {
        case 0: // Coordenada Invalida.
            System.err.println("Coordenada invalida. Comprueba lo introducido.");
            break;
        case 1: // Reiniciar el mismo.
            uno.setTablero(tab_bckup);
            uno.setToques();
            i = 0;
            break;
        case 2: // Nuevo tablero.
            uno.RellenarTablero();
            uno.setToques();
            i = 0;
            break;
        case 3: // Mostrar calificación.
            uno.mostarCalificacion();
            uno.ImprimirPartida();
            break;
        case 4: // Cambiar de nivel.
            uno.Datos(1);
            uno.RellenarTablero();
            uno.setToques();
            i = 0;
            break;
        case 5: // Salir
            break;
        case 6: // Coordenada valida.
            uno.DarToque();
            uno.SumarToques();
            uno.ImprimirPartida();
            break;
        }
        uno.ComprobarTablero();
        completado = uno.getEstado();
    } while (completado == false || (opc != 5));
```

[Enlace al código](https://pastebin.com/raw/5jXrywrc)

Dispongo de otra clase que crea un tablero pero no creo que sea necesaria para este error.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. También a leer [ask]. Por favor, no publiques imágenes de código, el sitio soporta la publicación de código fuente y le da el formato apropiado. No debes publicar todo tu proyecto, solamente un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este es un error típico de interpretar literalmente la condición.

```
(completado == false || (opc != 5))
```

Esto es verdad cuando `completado` es igual a falso, cuando `opc` != 5, y cuando se dan las dos condiciones. Es decir que mientras al menos una de las dos opciones sea verdadera la condición es verdadera.

Tu intención real es que la condición se cumpla cuando `completado` es igual a falso **Y** a la vez `opc` sea diferente de 5.

```
(completado == false && (opc != 5))
```

Esta condición es verdad cuando `completado` es igual a falso y cuando `opc` != 5 al mismo tiempo.

Comment: mejor explicado que lo mio

Answer (score 4):

`completado == false o opc sea diferente de 5`

Este es el error. Realmente la condicion de salida del bucle deberia ser:

```
 mientras completado == false Y opc diferente de 5.
```

En tu caso, la condicion del bucle deberia ser:

> while ( (completado == false) && (opc != 5))

Comment: no. Con una sola es suficiente. Estamos haciendo un AND. Si una de ellas es falsa, toda la condicion lo es.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!