# Programa se ingresa a while cuando no debería

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de programación, y estaba intentando predecir el error de que una persona no ingresará alguno de los dos valores contemplados por el programa, y no quiere salir del while (que es con lo que estoy intentando prevenir el error) **usando cualquiera de las dos opciones pedidas**.

```
       String gender;
    int age, pulse = 0;
   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Calculadora de Pulsaciones, inserte M si es hombre o F si es mujer");
    gender = sc.nextLine(); // LEER GENERO
    
    while(gender.toUpperCase() != "M" || gender.toUpperCase() != "F"){
        System.out.println("Hubo un error, inserte M si es hombre o F si es mujer");
        gender = sc.nextLine(); // LEER GENERO 
    }
    
    System.out.println("Inserte la edad");
    age = sc.nextInt();
    
    switch(gender.toUpperCase()){
        case "M":
            pulse = (220 - age)/10;
        case "F":
            pulse = (210 - age)/10;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Su pulso debe ser: " + pulse);
}
```

Comment: En el while usa condición and en lugar de or.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Do while se repite cuando no deberia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264460/do-while-se-repite-cuando-no-deberia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como parametro de while usas un **OR ||** donde los lee como verdaderos o falsos en constante (en este caso), con lo cual no sale del parametro si se quiere indicar bien, el uso de **AND &&** es lo que buscas.

```
while (!gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && !gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F"));
```

Pero también tienes otros fallos que no enfocas y dan error sin que lo notes, en ese switch tienes dos casos, donde uno aunque lo indiques el programa pasara completamente de el.

```
switch(gender.toUpperCase()){
    case "M":
        pulse = (220 - age)/10;
    case "F":
        pulse = (210 - age)/10;
}
```

Sin un `break;` esa variable de pulse siempre se sobrescribirá con la del case F, aparte de que puede darte un error de no haber inicializado ese String.

```
    switch(gender.toUpperCase()){
        case "M":
            pulse = (220 - age)/10;
            break;
        case "F":
            pulse = (210 - age)/10;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error no valido: " + gender.toUpperCase());
```

Algo por este estilo, ese default te ayuda de que sino se inicia bien el string salte el error. Indicar un `break;` en el default también es buena practica aunque por lógica no lo lleguemos a usar.

Al final me quedo así, lo dejo por si te sirve.

```
    String gender;
    int age, pulse;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Calculadora de Pulsaciones, inserte M si es hombre o F si es mujer");
        gender = sc.nextLine(); // LEER GENERO

        if (!gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && !gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            System.out.println("Hubo un error, inserte M si es hombre o F si es mujer");
            gender = sc.nextLine(); // LEER GENERO
        }

    } while (!gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && !gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F"));

    System.out.print("Indique su edad: ");
    age = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    switch(gender.toUpperCase()){
        case "M":
            pulse = (220 - age)/10;
            break;
        case "F":
            pulse = (210 - age)/10;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error no valido: " + gender.toUpperCase());
    }
    System.out.println("Su pulso debe ser: " + pulse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencionaron debes usar un AND `&&` 
Para comparar cadenas o caracteres se recomienda usar los metodos `equals()` o usar el `equalsIgnoreCase();`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String gender;
        int age, pulse = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Calculadora de Pulsaciones, inserte M si es hombre o F si es mujer");
        gender = sc.nextLine(); // LEER GENERO

        while (!gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && !gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            System.out.println("Hubo un error, inserte M si es hombre o F si es mujer");
            gender = sc.nextLine(); // LEER GENERO 
        }

        System.out.println("Inserte la edad");
        age = sc.nextInt();

        switch (gender.toUpperCase()) {
            case "M":
                pulse = (220 - age) / 10;
            case "F":
                pulse = (210 - age) / 10;
        }

        System.out.println("Su pulso debe ser: " + pulse);
    }
```